# Algorithm exercise. Election time calculation

Tags: algorithm, time, execution

I've got this exercise:

```
Test (int n)
  if(n<=81) then return 1
  k=1
  h=1
  while(k<=n)
    for j=1 to k do
      c++
    k=k+2
  return 9*h + Test(n/3)
```

and i have to calculate the execution time in the worst case. I'm a little bit confused because in a similar exercise:

```
Exercise(int n)
  c=1
  m=n*n
  while(m>1) do
    for j=1 to m do
      c++
    m=m/2
  if(n>1) then Exercise(n/2)
```

the execution time is (n^2) because m starts from n^2 and is divided every time by 2 so n^2/2^i=1

where i is the iteration.

At first exercise i've got k=k+2 so every iteration is added by 2.

n+2*i=1 --> i=n/2

so the execution time would be

```
n/2
∑ n+2*i = (n^2)
i=0
```

I think is correct but something is telling me that i should consider the last line `return 9*h + Test(n/3)`

Comment: In first you have to think about  loops . First loop will go for `n/2` times and  second loop for `k` times .

Comment: hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series